# How to determine an appropriate `scale` in tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer?

Tags: tensorflow, regularized

I saw a wide range of the `scale` values set for [`tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/l2_regularizer) in different applications. Is there a general rule to determine the value of `scale`? For example,

(1) Do we need to consider the number of elements in weights and normalize it using `scale`?

(2) If the mean square error (MSE) is part of the loss, what is the appropriate ratio between MSE and the l2 loss?